# Example using sharpmap in mvc asp.net

Tags: shapefile, asp.net, sharpmap

I am wanting to open shapefile files in a ASP.NET MVC application, was researching and found sharpmap but have not found examples of how to implement the MVC. Does anyone have any examples to help me develop.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you..Its a getting start with sharp map:

[Creating an Interactive Map in ASP.NET 2.0 Using SharpMap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12457/Creating-an-Interactive-Map-in-ASP-NET-Using-S)